# How to find value from data’s index?

Tags: javascript

I have the data:

```
0101400
0102500
0103300
0202500
0205600
etc
```

How to get value from index data in javascript

```
0101 value 400
0102 value 500
0103 value 300
0202 value 500
0205 value 600
```

Please help, thank you..

Comment: You should describe your problem more specifically

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your query ?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem and update your inputs and output, and add what you have tried.

Comment: is it a string or integer and what is the length of index

Comment: I have edited the question as it seemed something like this, in the code section

Comment: Do you mean you want 400 from index 0101, 500 from index 0102 ... n so ?

Answer (score 1):

If its in string format you can use sub string function to get the last 3 digits and the other part

```js
var data = ["0101400", "0102500", "0103300", "0202500", "0205600"];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var index = data[i].substr(data[i].length -3, 3);
  var value = data[i].substr(0, data[i].length -3);
  console.log(value + " value " + index );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following`RegExp` with `String.protoype.replace`

```js
let data = '0101400 0102500 0103300 0202500 0205600';
let output = data.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{3})\s?/g, '$1 value $2 \n');
console.log(output)
```